# Problems with no-undef on React.js

Tags: reactjs, svm

I am actually looking at a tutorial for React.js and I encountered this error.

src\components\counter.jsx
Line 19:50:  'product' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

My code is actually looking like this:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0,
     };

    handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    }


    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button
              onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
              className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
            >
              Increment
            </button>
          </div>
        );
    }

    getBadgeClasses() {
        let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
        classes += (this.state.count === 0) ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }

    formatCount () {
        const { count } = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: `product` not defined in this line `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}` as the error says, just remove the `product` variable, it has no meaning in your logic

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response!

It was not my logic tho, it was in the tutorial that I was watching.

I was trying to give the attribute of a product for a counter.